app script code running slowly: google slides
Please Help
my app script code takes too long to run. the script is meant to locate data from a spreadsheet then get images from another sheet and insert them into a google slide. the images take way too long to import because there are way too many of them. please help because I don't know how I would make the code quicker.
function myFunction() {
  var textboxvalue 
  var stop = 0
  var mapspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1VMox84RztQX_A1FDLPAdqVsop_pTdxMtASiempOvfIw')//map sheet
  var Local = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var LocalFile = DriveApp.getFileById(Local.getId());
  var name = LocalFile.getOwner().getName();
  var pfp = LocalFile.getOwner().getPhotoUrl();
  var Gameserver = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OV9pHfPgYwNGSagejbVyb2u0pCzdn7uY6at_cgXzWdc");//server sheet
  var PlayerData = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1nLVvr8crxDwZA3ly_iEqctTzEW8xpkcqw6EQ6Yr9OV0");//data sheet
  var Clients = Gameserver.setCurrentCell(Gameserver.getRange('A2')).getValue();//get number of created clients
  var cellthingy = Clients + 1
  var PlayerDataFinder = PlayerData.createTextFinder(name).findNext();//get PlayerData cell if there is one
  var PlayerRow = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerDataFinder).getRow()
  var positionX = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('C' + PlayerRow)).getValue()//get X and Y coordinates
  var positionY = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('D' + PlayerRow)).getValue()
  Local.addEditor("exampleemail@example.com")//give me access to the slide
  console.log("Clients: " + Clients);//print number of created clients
  console.log("Name: " + name)//player name
  console.log(pfp)//player pfp
  //TODO - Add check to make sure I am not updating the servers
  if (Gameserver.setCurrentCell(Gameserver.getRange('A3')).getValue() != 1) {
    const slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0];//get only slide in presentation
    slide.getShapes().forEach(shape => {//this is here to find the textbox and takethe text from it
      if (shape.getShapeType() == SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX) {
        textboxvalue = shape.getText().asString().trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
        shape.remove();
        if (textboxvalue.length == 0) {
          console.log(textboxvalue.length)
          console.log("no new inputs")
          stop = "1"
        }
      }
    });
    slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 540, 70, 170, 300);
    var images = slide.getImages().toString()
    slide.getImages().forEach(image => {//this is here to find the textbox and take the text from it
      image.remove();
    });
    slide.insertImage(pfp, 248.5, 165, 45, 45)
    console.log(images)
    try {
      if (1 != stop) {//if no new inputs don't run the script
        console.log('loading data')
        var PlayerDataFinder = PlayerData.createTextFinder(name).findNext();//get PlayerData cell if there is one
        var PlayerRow = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerDataFinder).getRow()
        var positionX = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('C' + PlayerRow)).getValue()//get X and Y coordinates
        var positionY = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('D' + PlayerRow)).getValue()
        var oldpositionX = positionX
        var oldpositionY = positionY
        console.log(textboxvalue)
        console.log(positionX.toString() + "," + positionY.toString())
        console.log('got data!');
        if (textboxvalue == "up") {//giant if statement thingy to check what is typed in the box
          console.log("moving player up!")
          PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('D' + PlayerRow)).setValue(positionY + 1)
          GetMap(positionX, positionY + 1)
        } else {
          if (textboxvalue == "down") {
            console.log("moving player down!")
            PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('D' + PlayerRow)).setValue(positionY - 1)
            GetMap(positionX, positionY - 1)
          } else {
            if (textboxvalue == "left") {
              console.log("moving player left!")
              PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('C' + PlayerRow)).setValue(positionX - 1)
              GetMap(positionX - 1, positionY)
            } else {
              if (textboxvalue == "right") {
                console.log("moving player right!")
                PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('C' + PlayerRow)).setValue(positionX + 1)
                GetMap(positionX + 1, positionY)
              } else {
                if (textboxvalue == "block up") {

                } else {
                  if (textboxvalue == "attack up") {

                  } else {
                    if (textboxvalue == "block down") {

                    } else {
                      if (textboxvalue == "attack down") {

                      } else {
                        if (textboxvalue == "block left") {

                        } else {
                          if (textboxvalue == "attack left") {

                          } else {
                            if (textboxvalue == "block right") {

                            } else {
                              if (textboxvalue == "attack right") {
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        positionX = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('C' + PlayerRow)).getValue()//get new X value
        positionY = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('D' + PlayerRow)).getValue()//get new Y value
        var positioncombined = positionX.toString() + "," + positionY.toString()//combine them
        console.log(positioncombined)
        positionX = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('C' + PlayerRow)).getValue() + 1//get new X value
        positionY = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('D' + PlayerRow)).getValue()//get new Y value
        var positioncombined = positionX.toString() + "," + positionY.toString()//combine them
        try {
          var positioncellfinder = mapspreadsheet.setActiveSheet(mapspreadsheet.getSheetByName('coordinates')).createTextFinder(positioncombined).findNext().getA1Notation();//find position cell
          console.log(positioncellfinder)
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
          console.log('Can\'t get position cell!, undoing movement')
          PlayerData.getRange('C' + PlayerRow).setValue(oldpositionX);
          PlayerData.getRange('D' + PlayerRow).setValue(oldpositionY);
        }
      } else {
        GetMap(positionX, positionY);
      }
    } catch (error) {//check if threre is no playerdata
      console.log(error);
      if (error == "{ [Exception: Invalid argument: cell] name: 'Exception' }") {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('No data found! creating data');
        PlayerData.getRange("A" + cellthingy).setValue(name);
        PlayerData.getRange("B" + cellthingy).setValue(pfp);
        PlayerData.getRange('C' + cellthingy).setValue("0");//set X to 0
        PlayerData.getRange('D' + cellthingy).setValue("0");//set Y to 0
        Gameserver.setCurrentCell(Gameserver.getRange('A2')).setValue(Clients + 1)
        console.log('Done');
      }
    }
  }
}
function Getcellimage(X, Y) {
  try {
    var mapspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1VMox84RztQX_A1FDLPAdqVsop_pTdxMtASiempOvfIw')//map 
    console.log("textfinder start")
    var positioncellfinder = mapspreadsheet.setActiveSheet(mapspreadsheet.getSheetByName('coordinates')).createTextFinder(X.toString() +
      "," + Y.toString()).findNext().getA1Notation();//find image cell
    console.log("textfinder end")
    var imgthingy = mapspreadsheet.setActiveSheet(mapspreadsheet.getSheetByName('IMG')).setCurrentCell(mapspreadsheet.getRange(positioncellfinder)).getValue()//get img
    console.log(imgthingy)
    return (imgthingy)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(imgthingy + "cellimageerror:" + error)
    return ("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R9qlYwqWSlWhrDLVTJLaJQKet3Smt9R8/view?usp=sharing")
  }
}
function GetMap(PLAYERX, PLAYERY) {
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 1, 0)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -1, 0)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 0, 1)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 0, -1)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 1, 1)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 1, -1)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -1, 1)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -1, -1)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -1, 2)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 0, 2)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 1, 2)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -1, -2)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 0, -2)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -2, 2)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -2, 0)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -2, -1)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -2, -2)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 1, -2)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 2, 1)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 2, 2)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 2, 0)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 2, -1)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 2, -2)
  Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -2, 1)
}
function GetIdFromUrl(url) {
  console.log(url)
  return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
}
function Getandinsertimage(PLAYERX, PLAYERY, X, Y) {
  const slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0];//get only slide in presentation
  var bread = DriveApp.getFileById(GetIdFromUrl(Getcellimage(PLAYERX + X, PLAYERY + Y)))
  slide.insertImage(bread, 248.5 + 45 * X, 165 - 45 * Y, 45, 45)
}


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

My first impression is you are openById a lot of files and repeatedly.  See Best Practices.  I would recommend you rethink your logic.

I used cache and realized that it is spending most of its time inserting the image is there anyway to fix this?

Usually the api methods are faster. You may try  Google slides api(via Advanced Google services or UrlFetchApp)

For a start I would try this.  I've reduced the many of the openById to one call and then passed as a parameter to the other functions.  There is no way for anyone to test this because it relies on a lot of data and files not available to us.
function myFunction() {
  var textboxvalue 
  var stop = 0
  var mapspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1VMox84RztQX_A1FDLPAdqVsop_pTdxMtASiempOvfIw')//map sheet
  var Local = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var LocalFile = DriveApp.getFileById(Local.getId());
  var name = LocalFile.getOwner().getName();
  var pfp = LocalFile.getOwner().getPhotoUrl();
  var Gameserver = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OV9pHfPgYwNGSagejbVyb2u0pCzdn7uY6at_cgXzWdc");//server sheet
  var PlayerData = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1nLVvr8crxDwZA3ly_iEqctTzEW8xpkcqw6EQ6Yr9OV0");//data sheet
  var Clients = Gameserver.setCurrentCell(Gameserver.getRange('A2')).getValue();//get number of created clients
  var cellthingy = Clients + 1
  var PlayerDataFinder = PlayerData.createTextFinder(name).findNext();//get PlayerData cell if there is one
  var PlayerRow = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerDataFinder).getRow()
  var positionX = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('C' + PlayerRow)).getValue()//get X and Y coordinates
  var positionY = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('D' + PlayerRow)).getValue()
  Local.addEditor("exampleemail@example.com")//give me access to the slide
  console.log("Clients: " + Clients);//print number of created clients
  console.log("Name: " + name)//player name
  console.log(pfp)//player pfp
  //TODO - Add check to make sure I am not updating the servers
  if (Gameserver.setCurrentCell(Gameserver.getRange('A3')).getValue() != 1) {
    const slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0];//get only slide in presentation
    slide.getShapes().forEach(shape => {//this is here to find the textbox and takethe text from it
      if (shape.getShapeType() == SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX) {
        textboxvalue = shape.getText().asString().trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
        shape.remove();
        if (textboxvalue.length == 0) {
          console.log(textboxvalue.length)
          console.log("no new inputs")
          stop = "1"
        }
      }
    });
    slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 540, 70, 170, 300);
    var images = slide.getImages().toString()
    slide.getImages().forEach(image => {//this is here to find the textbox and take the text from it
      image.remove();
    });
    slide.insertImage(pfp, 248.5, 165, 45, 45)
    console.log(images)
    try {
      if (1 != stop) {//if no new inputs don't run the script
        console.log('loading data')
        var PlayerDataFinder = PlayerData.createTextFinder(name).findNext();//get PlayerData cell if there is one
        var PlayerRow = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerDataFinder).getRow()
        var positionX = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('C' + PlayerRow)).getValue()//get X and Y coordinates
        var positionY = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('D' + PlayerRow)).getValue()
        var oldpositionX = positionX
        var oldpositionY = positionY
        console.log(textboxvalue)
        console.log(positionX.toString() + "," + positionY.toString())
        console.log('got data!');
        if (textboxvalue == "up") {//giant if statement thingy to check what is typed in the box
          console.log("moving player up!")
          PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('D' + PlayerRow)).setValue(positionY + 1)
          GetMap(slide,mapspreadsheet,positionX, positionY + 1)
        } else {
          if (textboxvalue == "down") {
            console.log("moving player down!")
            PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('D' + PlayerRow)).setValue(positionY - 1)
            GetMap(slide,mapspreadsheet,positionX, positionY - 1)
          } else {
            if (textboxvalue == "left") {
              console.log("moving player left!")
              PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('C' + PlayerRow)).setValue(positionX - 1)
              GetMap(slide,mapspreadsheet,positionX - 1, positionY)
            } else {
              if (textboxvalue == "right") {
                console.log("moving player right!")
                PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('C' + PlayerRow)).setValue(positionX + 1)
                GetMap(slide,mapspreadsheet,positionX + 1, positionY)
              } else {
                if (textboxvalue == "block up") {

                } else {
                  if (textboxvalue == "attack up") {

                  } else {
                    if (textboxvalue == "block down") {

                    } else {
                      if (textboxvalue == "attack down") {

                      } else {
                        if (textboxvalue == "block left") {

                        } else {
                          if (textboxvalue == "attack left") {

                          } else {
                            if (textboxvalue == "block right") {

                            } else {
                              if (textboxvalue == "attack right") {
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        positionX = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('C' + PlayerRow)).getValue()//get new X value
        positionY = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('D' + PlayerRow)).getValue()//get new Y value
        var positioncombined = positionX.toString() + "," + positionY.toString()//combine them
        console.log(positioncombined)
        positionX = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('C' + PlayerRow)).getValue() + 1//get new X value
        positionY = PlayerData.setCurrentCell(PlayerData.getRange('D' + PlayerRow)).getValue()//get new Y value
        var positioncombined = positionX.toString() + "," + positionY.toString()//combine them
        try {
          var positioncellfinder = mapspreadsheet.setActiveSheet(mapspreadsheet.getSheetByName('coordinates')).createTextFinder(positioncombined).findNext().getA1Notation();//find position cell
          console.log(positioncellfinder)
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
          console.log('Can\'t get position cell!, undoing movement')
          PlayerData.getRange('C' + PlayerRow).setValue(oldpositionX);
          PlayerData.getRange('D' + PlayerRow).setValue(oldpositionY);
        }
      } else {
        GetMap(slide,mapspreadsheet,positionX, positionY);
      }
    } catch (error) {//check if threre is no playerdata
      console.log(error);
      if (error == "{ [Exception: Invalid argument: cell] name: 'Exception' }") {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('No data found! creating data');
        PlayerData.getRange("A" + cellthingy).setValue(name);
        PlayerData.getRange("B" + cellthingy).setValue(pfp);
        PlayerData.getRange('C' + cellthingy).setValue("0");//set X to 0
        PlayerData.getRange('D' + cellthingy).setValue("0");//set Y to 0
        Gameserver.setCurrentCell(Gameserver.getRange('A2')).setValue(Clients + 1)
        console.log('Done');
      }
    }
  }
}
function Getcellimage(mapspreadsheet,X, Y) {
  try {
    console.log("textfinder start")
    var positioncellfinder = mapspreadsheet.setActiveSheet(mapspreadsheet.getSheetByName('coordinates')).createTextFinder(X.toString() +
      "," + Y.toString()).findNext().getA1Notation();//find image cell
    console.log("textfinder end")
    var imgthingy = mapspreadsheet.setActiveSheet(mapspreadsheet.getSheetByName('IMG')).setCurrentCell(mapspreadsheet.getRange(positioncellfinder)).getValue()//get img
    console.log(imgthingy)
    return (imgthingy)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(imgthingy + "cellimageerror:" + error)
    return ("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R9qlYwqWSlWhrDLVTJLaJQKet3Smt9R8/view?usp=sharing")
  }
}
function GetMap(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY) {
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 1, 0)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -1, 0)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 0, 1)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 0, -1)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 1, 1)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 1, -1)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -1, 1)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -1, -1)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -1, 2)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 0, 2)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 1, 2)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -1, -2)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 0, -2)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -2, 2)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -2, 0)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -2, -1)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -2, -2)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 1, -2)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 2, 1)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 2, 2)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 2, 0)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 2, -1)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, 2, -2)
  Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, -2, 1)
}
function GetIdFromUrl(url) {
  console.log(url)
  return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
}
function Getandinsertimage(slide,mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX, PLAYERY, X, Y) {
  var bread = DriveApp.getFileById(GetIdFromUrl(Getcellimage(mapspreadsheet,PLAYERX + X, PLAYERY + Y)))
  slide.insertImage(bread, 248.5 + 45 * X, 165 - 45 * Y, 45, 45)
}


the script took 43.513 seconds to run. I think the slowdown is from inserting the images is there like a better way to insert images or something?

The only other option I can think of is to use batchUpdate

You can find a description of how to use batchUpdate here
